# tasm Trouble with output

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, tasm

I am having a lot of trouble figuring out which register holds the information that I need to output. I have tried byte ptr si, bl, bx with incs and decs, but I just flat out cannot figure out what I need to do to be able to output. At the moment it just doesn't output anything. What I need to output is the input, except replacing all the gaps with the character before it, so "a b c" becomes "aabbc".

Here is the code that I just cannot figure out.

```
.MODEL SMALL ;defines memory model
.STACK 100H ;reserves memory space
.DATA
insert equ 0ah
outsert equ 9h
ENDL equ '$'
GAP equ ' '
EMPTY equ ' '
newline db 0ah, 0dh, '$'
;db 120h dup (?) ;reserve 120h bytes of space
Buff db 250
clen db ?
_chr db 250 dup (?) ;reserve 250 bytes of space for line
.CODE
START:
mov     dx, @data               ; perkelti data i registra ax
mov     ds, dx                  ; nustatyti ds rodyti i data segmenta

;user input
lea dx, Buff ;load address
mov ah, insert ;insert into ah
int 21h ;close

; putting length into cx
xor cx, cx
mov cl, clen
mov si, offset clen ;loads offset part

;if line is empty, end
cmp cx, 0 ;compare
;testing if end of the line
je FINISH

mov dx, offset newline ;from the 3'rd byte
mov ah, outsert
int 21h; ;finsihing up, closing

;pre-checking
PREP:
dec cx
inc si
cmp byte ptr [si], EMPTY
je PREP
jmp CHECK

CHECK:
dec cx ;decrement starting pointer by 1
inc si ;raise starting pointer by 1
cmp cx, 0 ;comparing if empty
je CONT ;jei paskutinis, tai baigiamas ciklas
cmp byte ptr [si], GAP ;2 operands compare
je CHANGE ;if gap found, then off to this cycle to change symbol
jmp CHECK
CHANGE:
mov bl, byte ptr [si-1]
mov [si], bl
jmp CHECK ;returning to cycle
CONT:
; '$' at end of buffer
; vi points at last symbol
inc si
mov bl, ENDL
mov [si], bl

;output onto screen
;lea dx, Buff
;add ax, 2 ;from the 3'rd byte
;mov ah, outsert
;int 21h; ;finsihing up, closing
xor ch, ch
mov cl, clen
mov si, offset _chr
ciklas:
lodsb
mov bx, 2
;al
dec bx
jz FINISH
loop ciklas


;returning to DOS
FINISH:
mov ax, 4c00h ;exit
int 21h
```

If it is necessary, I will add in the cut out code, I removed it because I think that it is not vital to figuring out the output issues. I massively appreciate your patience with me.

Comment: You cut out relevant code ... people always do that when they want to be clever ... We don't know which buffer you operate on, `Buff` or `_chr`? Not sure what you wanted to do with the `add ax, 2` either. Anyway, the commented out code should have worked for `Buff`.

Comment: @Jester we also don't know with the [snip] if they initialised the _DS_ register appropriately.Okay the edit answers that lol

Comment: @Jester Duly noted. Added the code that was originally cut out. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commented out code should pretty much work, except you add 2 to `ax` instead of `dx`:

```
;output onto screen
lea dx, Buff+2
mov ah, outsert
int 21h; ;finsihing up, closing

;returning to DOS
FINISH:
mov ax, 4c00h ;exit
int 21h
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. Guess it shows how close one can be to the truth, miss it by that much and then go on a completely different route and miss the correct answer completely. Alright, now to return to my other tasm program where I have a looping and output problem. I'd ask here, but I don't want to push the goodwill of the people here, so I'll try to figure it out myself. Thanks.

Comment: @Anstane : Use turbo debugger if you are using TASM. Step through your code to see where your program might go wrong.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I am. I see where the code goes off (It's a JC that goes off despite me not needing it to), but it's not very clear to me what causes it to go off. If it didn't, the code I believe would work fine, as it then would print out the correct answer and then read the next line from the file. At least, in theory. Of course, I'm now just rambling pointlessly. The main question, the one posted, is answered, that's what matters here.